# How to create a pivot table with descending orders and margins in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
AGE               21        23       25 Grand Total
GENDER
F                NaN   87988.0  53532.0      141520
Grand Total  34323.0  141441.0  76986.0      252750
M            34323.0   53453.0  23454.0      111230
```

I want grand total to be printed at the end.how can i do that?

Comment: Yes this is possible, can you please share data and code that got you to this point?

Comment: In given pivot table rows and column should be in descending order also.

Comment: _rows and column should be in descending order_ of what? It appears to me that this requirement contradicts _I want grand total to be printed at the end._

Comment: rows should be in descending order of Gender and column of age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want grand total to be printed at the end.

The totals would appear at the end had you created the pivot table like

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values=…, index=['GENDER'], columns=['AGE'],
               aggfunc=np.sum, margins=True, margins_name='Grand Total')
```

So, consider adapting your creation of the table to the above. Otherwise, as braintho asked, you'd really have to *share data and code that got you to this point*.

> rows should be in descending order of Gender and column of age.
>   By doing this Gender and Age will be in ascending order. I want them in descending order. If i apply sorting then grand total also get sorted, but i don't want to sort Grand total.

Since the rows and columns are already sorted in ascending order, we can just *reverse* them (except the grand totals) by combining (reversed) slicing and reindexing. Let's assume the above DataFrame value has been assigned to the variable `t`. With

```
r = t.index[-2::-1].tolist()+t.index[-1:].tolist()
```

we get the wanted row indexes `['M', 'F', 'Grand Total']`; and with

```
c = t.columns[-2::-1].tolist()+t.columns[-1:].tolist()
```

we get the wanted column indexes `[25, 23, 21, 'Grand Total']`. With these, we can simply

```
t.reindex(r, c)
```

and get

```
AGE               25        23       21  Grand Total
GENDER
M            23454.0   53453.0  34323.0     111230.0
F            53532.0   87988.0      NaN     141520.0
Grand Total  76986.0  141441.0  34323.0     252750.0
```

Comment: Actually, By doing this Gender and Age will be in ascending order. I want them in descending order. If i apply sorting then grand total also get sorted, but i don't want to sort Grand total.

Comment: I amended the answer.